# How to count and access the worksheets of Excel in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, codeigniter

Hi i am trying to fetch the records of excel sheet and store in my database. I am success fully add the excel first sheet but not able to get second sheet of excel and its records.
 i am using this code and get the first sheet `$this -> load -> library('Excel');

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($load_file);
$cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
```

`
Suppose in image its 3 worksheets in one excel. HOw can i access to second and third worksheet?? Please give me some help. Thanks  
[image: how to count excel worksheets in PHP codeigniter]

Answer (score 1):

Try using [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) on reading your excel file.

```
function read_excel(){
        //Load library plugin
        $this->load->library('excel');

        /** Error reporting */
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
        define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

        //Open excel file
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(FCPATH."file.xls");

        // go through your worksheet if you have multiple worksheet inside the excel file
        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
            //read each row of the worksheet
            foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                //get cells
                $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
                $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
                foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                    //get cell values
                    $cell->getCalculatedValue();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

tweak this code in your need.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am already using this. I am looking for how can i access to my second and third worksheet??<br> i am using this code `$this -> load -> library('Excel');

 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($load_file);
 $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
`

Comment: @user3548569 Try the sample function above I used it in my program for reading multiple sheets inside an excel file. and thanks for the down vote :P

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i get my own Answer and its super fast and i am showing in my Answer too. Thanks for support :)

Answer (score 1):

When i am Exploring **PHPExcel.php** i get the solution that i am going to share with other too.

```
 $target_file   = $path . basename($_FILES["files"]["name"]);// storing the excel file to folder
 $file_id       = basename($_FILES["files"]["name"]);
 $FileType  = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

 $load_file = $target_file;

 $update4       = array('file_id' => $file_id,);

 $this -> load -> library('Excel');

 $objPHPExcel   = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($load_file);

 $sheet_count   = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();// this function give me worksheets count.
 for($s=0; $s<$sheet_count; $s++){// using for lop to get specific worksheet data
    $cell_collection= $objPHPExcel->getSheet($s)->getCellCollection();

    foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
        $column     = $objPHPExcel -> getSheet() -> getCell($cell) -> getColumn();
        $row        = $objPHPExcel -> getSheet() -> getCell($cell) -> getRow();
        $data_value = $objPHPExcel -> getSheet() -> getCell($cell) -> getValue();

        if ($row == 1) {// if you have header in your excel or want to store then store in header.
            $header[$s][$row][$column] = $data_value;
        } else {// i get my meaningful data from here :)
            $arr_data[$s][$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }
    }
}// end of for loop for getting the work sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for store multiple tab or multiple excel in one excel sheet.

```
                        $path                   = $_FILES["product_excel_name"]["tmp_name"];
                        $object                 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
                        $sheet_count            = $object->getSheetCount();// this function give me worksheets count.
                        $sheet_data             = $object->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
                        
                        
                        for($s=0; $s<$sheet_count; $s++){// using for lop to get specific worksheet data
                           $cell_collection     = $object->getSheet($s)->getCellCollection();
                           
                           foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
                               
                                $column         = $object -> getSheet($s) -> getCell($cell) -> getColumn();
                                $row            = $object -> getSheet($s) -> getCell($cell) -> getRow();
                                $data_value     = $object -> getSheet($s) -> getCell($cell) -> getValue();
                                
                                if ($row == 1) {// if you have header in your excel or want to store then store in header.
                                    $header[$s][$row][$column] = $data_value;
                                    
                                } else {// i get my meaningful data from here :)
                                    $arr_data[$s][$row][$column] = $data_value;
                                }
                           }
                           
                       }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.